# Filtering Xdocument by multiple values

Tags: xml, linq

I have an XML like this :

```
- <root>
- <YEAR>
  <list_item  child_id="0" list_entry_id="1">2012</list_item> 
  <list_item  child_id="0" list_entry_id="2">2011</list_item> 
  <list_item  child_id="0" list_entry_id="3">2010</list_item> 
</YEAR>
</root>
```

I want to remove some nodes/years from the above xml based on a list_entry_id. This filter can be multiple values also. eg : want to filter the node with list_entry_id in (1,2). I tried the below linq query, it works for only single filter.

```
  string sXML="xmlstring";
     string syear="1,2";
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sXML);
      doc.Element("root").Element("YEAR").Elements("list_item").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("list_entry_id") != syear).Remove();
```

Please help to get a linq query which can filter multiple values

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within `Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("list_entry_id") != syear)` - you're comparing an individual `list_entry_id` to your entire filter string.

In the simplest case when your filter string is `1`, this will work, as the there will be a matching `list_entry_id`, but as soon as you begin to add anything else to the filter, e.g `1,2` as above, you will no longer find a matching `list_entry_id`.

There are several approaches you could take to get your desired result. One that's not too far away from what you already have (assuming that you need to accept your filter as a string), would be to split the filter string, and use the result to remove the unwanted nodes:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<root><YEAR><list_item child_id=\"0\" list_entry_id=\"1\">2012</list_item><list_item child_id=\"0\" list_entry_id=\"2\">2011</list_item><list_item child_id=\"0\" list_entry_id=\"3\">2010</list_item></YEAR></root>");

string syear="1,2";

string[] validIds= syear.Split(',');

doc
.Element("root")
.Element("YEAR")
.Elements("list_item")
.Where(x => !validIds.Contains(x.Attribute("list_entry_id").Value)).Remove();
```

Which is essentially saying, if the id is not contained within the valid ids, remove the node in question.

Which you could also re-write as:

```
doc
.Descendants("list_item")
.Where(x => !validIds.Contains(x.Attribute("list_entry_id").Value))
.Remove();
```